# Can't change min-height in email template D365 crm

Tags: html, css, email-templates, dynamics-crm-365

I am having trouble changing the min-height in email templates in marketing D365 crm.
I have tried both via the UI to change the min-height size (see image) and the html, but the size pops back to its original again. I've tried removing !important from the css too in case that would've helped but it didn't.

This is not a problem on 1 column, but on parts with several columns.

Anyone got any ideas?

[image]

This is what the HTML looks like (only displaying an empty 2 column).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>My Email Subject</title>
            <meta name="referrer" content="never">
            <meta type="xrm/designer/setting" name="type" value="marketing-designer-content-editor-document">
            <meta type="xrm/designer/setting" name="layout-editable" value="marketing-designer-layout-editable">
            <meta type="xrm/designer/setting" name="layout-max-width" value="600px" datatype="text" label="Layout max width">
            <meta type="xrm/designer/setting" name="font-family" value="Verdana, Arial, sans-serif" datatype="font" label="Font Family">
            <meta type="xrm/designer/setting" name="body-text-size" value="14px" datatype="text" label="Body Font Size">
            <meta type="xrm/designer/setting" name="body-text-color" value="#000" datatype="color" label="Body Text Color">
            <meta type="xrm/designer/setting" name="outer-background" value="#FFFFF" datatype="color" label="Email Background">
            <style>
                body, div {
                    font-family: /* @font-family */
                    Verdana, /* @font-family */
                    Arial, /* @font-family */
                    sans-serif/* @font-family */
                    ;
                    font-size: /* @body-text-size */
                    14px/* @body-text-size */
                    ;
                    color: /* @body-text-color */
                    #000/* @body-text-color */
                    ;
                    background-color: /* @outer-background */
                    #fff/* @outer-background */
                    ;
                }

                div div {
                    background-color: transparent;
                }

                [data-layout="true"] {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    max-width: /* @layout-max-width */
                    600px/* @layout-max-width */
                    ;
                }

                p {
                    margin: 0px;
                    padding: 0px;
                    line-height: 20px;
                    mso-line-height-rule: at-least;
                }

                ul, ol {
                    margin-top: 15px;
                    margin-bottom: 15px;
                    line-height: 20px;
                    mso-line-height-rule: at-least;
                }

                p img {
                    max-width: 100%;
                }

                a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                }

                u a {
                    text-decoration: underline;
                }

                h2, h3, h4 {
                    margin: 0px;
                }

                .imageWrapper a img {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    border: 0px;
                }

                body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer {
                    display: block !important;
                }

                body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer.multi table {
                    table-layout: fixed;
                    height: auto !important;
                }

                body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer.multi td {
                    width: auto !important;
                    min-height:70px !important;
                }

                body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer.multi tr td  {
                    display: block;
                }

                body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer.multi .inner {
                    height: auto !important;
                    min-height: auto !important;
                }

                body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer .inner {
                    box-sizing: border-box
                }

                body[data-outlook-cycle] .outer {
                    width: auto !important;
                }

                body[data-outlook-cycle] .innerTable {
                    min-height: auto !important;
                }

                @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                    .columnContainerWrapper {
                        min-height: 70px !important;
                    }
                    a span {
                        line-height: inherit !important;
                    }
                }

                @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                    .tbContainer {display: block !important;}
                    .tbContainer.multi table {
                        table-layout: fixed;
                        height:auto !important;
                    }
                    .tbContainer.multi td {
                        width: auto !important;
                        min-height:70px !important;
                    }
                    .tbContainer.multi tr, .tbContainer.multi tr td {display: block}
                    .tbContainer.multi .inner {
                        height: auto !important;
                    }
                    .tbContainer .inner {box-sizing: border-box}
                    .outer {
                        width: auto !important;
                    }
                    .innerTable {
                        min-height: auto !important;
                    }
                }
            </style>
        <meta name="html-editor"></head>
        <body><div data-layout="true">
                <div data-section="true" class=""><table class="outer" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;width: 600px;display: block;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(253, 222, 207);">
                                    <table style="
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        " class="containerWrapper tbContainer multi" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td data-container="true" class="columnContainer" data-container-width="50" style="
            min-height: 70px;
            min-width: 15px;width: 290.00px;
            
        ;" id="container4cab7d4be62be1622552139868">
                                                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; min-height: 90px;" class="innerTable">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="columnContainer inner ui-sortable" style="height: 70px; min-width: 15px; padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; background-color: rgb(204, 208, 255);"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td data-container="true" class="columnContainer" data-container-width="50" style="
            min-height: 0px;
            min-width: 15px;width: 290.00px;
            
        ;" id="container0d27b048b79d51622552139868">
                                                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="innerTable" style="min-height: 90px;">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="columnContainer inner ui-sortable" style="height: 70px; min-width: 15px; padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; background-color: rgb(232, 244, 217);"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table></div>
            </div></body></html>
```

Looks like this in the editor though:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @lanpierre updated with code, in the most simple way. I think it is a bug in D365 or smt though and not a code problem (it is auto generated). But sure, if I can go around this problem that would be great!

Answer (score -1):

Was able to modify the height by adding the following CSS and removing the inline styles on the targeted elements:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>My Email Subject</title>
<style>
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.columnContainer {
height: 170px;
min-width: 15px;
padding: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-word;
background-color: rgb(204, 208, 255);
}
.columnContainer {
height: 170px;
min-width: 15px;
padding: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-word;
background-color: rgb(204, 208, 255);
}
td {
min-height: 70px;
min-width: 15px;
width: 290.00px;
}
.inner {
min-height: 70px;
min-width: 15px;
width: 290.00px;
background-color: rgb(204, 255, 226);
} 

/* below here is the original CSS*/
body, div {
font-family: /* @font-family */
Verdana, /* @font-family */
Arial, /* @font-family */
sans-serif/* @font-family */
;
font-size: /* @body-text-size */
14px/* @body-text-size */
;
color: /* @body-text-color */
#000/* @body-text-color */
;
background-color: /* @outer-background */
#fff/* @outer-background */
;
}
div div {
background-color: transparent;
}
[data-layout="true"] {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: /* @layout-max-width */
600px/* @layout-max-width */
;
}
p {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 20px;
mso-line-height-rule: at-least;
}
ul, ol {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
line-height: 20px;
mso-line-height-rule: at-least;
}
p img {
max-width: 100%;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
u a {
text-decoration: underline;
}
h2, h3, h4 {
margin: 0px;
}
.imageWrapper a img {
text-decoration: none;
border: 0px;
}
body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer {
display: block !important;
}
body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer.multi table {
table-layout: fixed;
height: auto !important;
}
body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer.multi td {
width: auto !important;
min-height:70px !important;
}
body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer.multi tr td  {
display: block;
}
body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer.multi .inner {
height: auto !important;
min-height: auto !important;
}
body[data-outlook-cycle] .tbContainer .inner {
box-sizing: border-box
}
body[data-outlook-cycle] .outer {
width: auto !important;
}
body[data-outlook-cycle] .innerTable {
min-height: auto !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.columnContainerWrapper {
min-height: 70px !important;
}
a span {
line-height: inherit !important;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.tbContainer {display: block !important;}
.tbContainer.multi table {
table-layout: fixed;
height:auto !important;
}
.tbContainer.multi td {
width: auto !important;
min-height:70px !important;
}
.tbContainer.multi tr, .tbContainer.multi tr td {display: block}
.tbContainer.multi .inner {
height: auto !important;
}
.tbContainer .inner {box-sizing: border-box}
.outer {
width: auto !important;
}
.innerTable {
min-height: auto !important;
}
}
</style>
<meta name="html-editor"></head>
<body><div data-layout="true">
<div data-section="true" class=""><table class="outer" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;width: 600px;display: block;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(253, 222, 207);">
<table style="
display: block;
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
" class="containerWrapper tbContainer multi" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td data-container="true" class="columnContainer" data-container-width="50" style="
min-height: 70px;
min-width: 15px;width: 290.00px;
;" id="container4cab7d4be62be1622552139868">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; min-height: 90px;" class="innerTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="columnContainer inner ui-sortable" style="height: 70px; min-width: 15px; padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; background-color: rgb(204, 208, 255);"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td data-container="true" class="columnContainer" data-container-width="50" style="
min-height: 0px;
min-width: 15px;width: 290.00px;
;" id="container0d27b048b79d51622552139868">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="innerTable" style="min-height: 90px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="columnContainer inner ui-sortable" style="height: 70px; min-width: 15px; padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; background-color: rgb(232, 244, 217);"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table> 
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></div>
</div></body></html>
```

Does look like the editor will also be applying styles though.

Came across this when looking into it further:

[how to create mail templates in custom entities](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/300210/how-to-create-mail-templates-in-custom-entities)